# How to receive POST data from gravity forms for custom script

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

In my functions.php file, I have the something like the following (from gravity forms):

```
add_action('gform_after_submission_500', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2);
function post_to_third_party($entry, $form) {

  $post_url = THEME_DIR . '/myscript/index.php';
  $body = array(
      'first_name' => $entry['1'], 
      'last_name' => $entry['2'], 
      'email' => $entry['3']
      );

  $request = new WP_Http();
  $response = $request->post($post_url, array('body' => $body));
}
```

What should i have in 'myscript/index.php' to receive the post data so that I can use it?

Comment: `$_POST['input_name']`

Comment: There is nothing when I var_dump($_POST) on myscript/index.php

Comment: what about `$_REQUEST`

Comment: I get PHPSESSID etc but none of the data

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$request->request( $post_url, array( 'method' => 'POST', 'body' => $body) );
```

Comment: I tried this and I'm still not getting anything on myscript/index.php.  The POST array is empty.  Any ideas why it's not going through?

Comment: @quietgrit sorry im not familiar with wordpress! though you can read their documentation to help you further :)

Answer (score 0):

The data returned by `/myscript/index.php` just needs to be in a format that can be handled by PHP when it is returned in the `$response` variable. I'm not an expert here but my default is to output the data as JSON via [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on the `/myscript/index.php` side and then parse that data via [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) when it is returned in the response.

```
$data = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
```

Comment: I tried json encoding the body and sending a content type of application/json but I still receive nothing on /myscript/index.php.  So frustrating!

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. It's essentially the same but try using wp_remote_post() instead of what you currently have ([example](http://pastie.org/9861094)).

Also, to confirm, is the request making it to your script at all?